# Can a sub class overload a method of a superclass that has been declared abstract

Tags: java, oop

I"m having an issue overloading a method that has been declared in an abstract superclass. Below is the superclass

```
public abstract class UserTask {
    public abstract void applyToBorrowABook(User user, Map<String,PriorityQueue<User>>listOfApplicants, List<Books>booksList);
```

below is also the subclass I'm having problems implementing

```
public class UserQueueImpl extends UserTask  {

    @Override
    public void applyToBorrowABook(User user, Map<String, Queue<User>> listOfApplicants, List<Books> booksList) {
        if(booksList.size()>0){
            for(Books b:booksList){
                if(b.getBookTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(user.getBookRequested())){
                    if(listOfApplicants.containsKey(user.getBookRequested())){
                        listOfApplicants.get(user.getBookRequested()).add(user);
                    }
                    else{
                        PriorityQueue<User>applicants=new PriorityQueue<>();
                        applicants.add(user);
                        listOfApplicants.put(user.getBookRequested(),applicants);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new BookNotFoundException("No book present in the library");
        }


    }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you want to implement the parent method, then you must stick to the required generic types.

Comment: Ok, so what is your problem? You never told us what's wrong.

Comment: I thought by overloading a method you can define a different generic type in the sub class parameter

Comment: Not only can you not do that, but you're using a parent class of PriorityQueue in your subclass, which doesn't make sense. And UserQueueImpl is using PriorityQueues anyway...